# Receiving EditText cannot use the ellipsize mode TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE error in Android 3.0

Tags: android

I am encountering a new error for me when writing an EditText in my android xml layout.
The code for the layout is:

```
            <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:padding="10dip" >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Full Name"
                        android:textColor="#372c24" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/reg_fullname"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Email:"
                        android:textColor="#372c24" />

                    **<EditText
                        android:id="@+id/reg_email"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext" />**

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Password"
                        android:textColor="#372c24" />

                    **<EditText
                        android:id="@+id/reg_password"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                        android:imeOptions="actionDone" />**

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/saveBtn"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:imeOptions="actionSend"
                        android:text="LOGIN" />
                </LinearLayout>
```

And the error trace is:

```
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #72: Error inflating class android.widget.EditText
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:644)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:479)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:391)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:347)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:224)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1777)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at com.bearing.inhouse.DashboardActivity.onCreate(DashboardActivity.java:38)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     ... 11 more
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:576)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     ... 27 more
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: EditText cannot use the ellipsize mode TextUtils.TruncateAt.MARQUEE
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.widget.EditText.setEllipsize(EditText.java:112)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:946)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:58)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:54)
04-23 09:11:56.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1692):     ... 30 more
```

I have used EditText before and i never got this error. I don't understand from the error log what i am supposed to do. Did you found this error in code before? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7252) where it's stated to use:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
```

This worked:

```
<EditText
       android:id="@+id/titleTxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:hint="title"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_normal" />
```

Hope it does the same for you.

Comment: I saw this and initially paid no attention to it. It indeed does work. THANK YOU very much. I lasted on resolving this issue on android 2 for hours.

Answer (score 1):

Set this property to edit text. Elipsize is working with disabled text editing:

```
android:lines="1"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
android:editable="false"
```

or use

```
setKeyListener(null);
```

Comment: Using android:singleLine="true" and android:ellipsize="end" worked for me